# load content of file into specific cell of a table

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert file contents into MySQL table's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101021/insert-file-contents-into-mysql-tables-column)

I want to load the content of a file into a specific cell of a table, or to be more precise i want to update a specific cell and the content of the cell after updating should be the content of a file.

Preferably by means of the command line. My first attempt that illustrate, what i want to achieve was;

```
mysql -p -u user -e "update my_table set body='`cat filename`' where id=x;" dbname
```

But of course mysql have trouble with special characters within the file. Alternatively i would agree with a perl one-liner.

Comment: I'm unclear on some details. Could you give a (short) example of a complete file, together with the SQL statements that you could use if that were the file?

Comment: (In particular, what I'm unclear on is: Is the entire file supposed to go into a single table-cell, or is each line of the file supposed to go into a separate row?)

Comment: @ruakh The entire file should be transferred into a single table-cell of an existing row. You are right 'column' is very misleading, i will change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the `LOAD_FILE` function given in the answer to the question that Charles Sprayberry links to above. That would look like this:

```
mysql -p -u user -e "update my_table set body=load_file('/path/to/filename') where id=x;" dbname
```

If that doesn't work out for you (e.g., due to permissions issues or whatnot), then you solve your problem differently, by using features of Bash and `sed` to fix your existing command, as follows:

Most special characters, such as newlines and whatnot, seem to be just fine inside single-quoted strings. The only characters that should be a problem are `'` (which would be interpreted as terminating the string) and `\` (which would be interpreted as introducing an escape sequence), and both of these can be addressed by prefixing a `\` (for example, `'\''` and `'\\'` are string literals denoting `'` and `\`, respectively). This `sed` script inserts a `\` before any `'` or `\`:

```
s/\('\|\\\)/\\\1/g
```

which you can invoke from Bash like this:

```
sed 's/\('"'"'\|\\\)/\\\1/g' filename
```

(for example, if `filename` contains this:

```
a \ b \ c
d ' e ' f
```

then `sed 's/\('"'"'\|\\\)/\\\1/g' filename` will print this:

```
a \\ b \\ c
d \' e \' f
```

). But you can't just wrap the above in `` `...` ``, because these characters are special to Bash as well, and it will get confused. (I'm assuming you're using Bash?) Instead, you need to use `$(...)`, which is a Bash notation that's equivalent to `` `...` `` except that it better handles various details like this. (I recommend always using `$(...)` over `` `...` ``.) So your overall command would be:

```
mysql -p -u user -e "update my_table set body='$(sed 's/\('"'"'\|\\\)/\\\1/g' filename)' where id=x;" dbname
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first suggestion works after i gave me the corresponding rights with `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO me@localhost`