# Reading a text file into an array with PHP - advise

Tags: php, mysql

Ive the following Code , a function take a list of usernames and put in them in array then execute    function called function get_all_friends  , Code works fine and no error , my question here how to adjust the code if ive bulk of usernames lets say like 10k ?

Like reading from file include all usernames name and put them in array using

```
$file_handle = fopen("users.txt")
```

please advise !

```
<?PHP
    $user1 = "usernamehere";
    $user2 = "usernamehere";
    $user3 = "usernamehere";
    $u[] = $user1;
    $u[] = $user2;
    $u[] = $user3;

    function get_all_friends($users) 
    {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET);
        $list = array();
        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            $result = $connection->get( 'friends/ids', array(
            "screen_name"=> $user)
            );

            foreach($result->ids as $friend) 
            {
                $list[] = $friend;
            }

        }
        return $list;
    }

    //call the function
    $result = get_all_friends($u);

    foreach($result as $res)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO friends (userid, name, grade, flag) VALUES ($res, 'name', 100, 0 ) ";
        mysql_query($query);    
    }

    //to print the databse result
    echo "row<br />";
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends");  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

Comment: check working example on official site: http://php.net/fopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work (untested):

```
$filename = "users.txt";
$file_handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($file_handle, filesize($filename));
$usernames = preg_split("/ (,|\\n) /", $contents);
fclose($file_handle);
```

The usernames must be separated by a comma or a new line.

Although, if you are positive that the usernames will only be separated by a new line OR a comma, this code will be faster:

```
$filename = "users.txt";
$file_handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($file_handle, filesize($filename));
// new line:
$usernames = explode("\n", $contents);
// or comma:
$usernames = explode(",", $contents);
fclose($handle);
```

Please choose only one of the $usernames definitions.

Comment: sound good  to me , but fclose($file_handle);  should be after the function executed  correct

Comment: fclose should come when you're done with the file. If you don't do anything with the file in the get_all_friends function, then it should come before you call the function.

Comment: get_all_friends function is my main function i should take each username from the file and extract friends ids from twitter and add them to databases (

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to answer the question, check `file(..)` - "Reads entire file into an array"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Although you probably don't want to be doing it this way, if the file is large you'll be much better off reading sequentially or doing some sort of direct import.

Comment: suggest something for direct import  , my file will  like 10k line each line 1 username

Comment: ok, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101021/insert-file-contents-into-mysql-tables-column